# Book for projective geometry

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

I am looking for a blue colored book about projective geometry，as I remember, on sheep or goat covers.

My friend suggested me two books before. I choose another one but recently I am interested in projective geometry.

Of course, the most fastest way to know about the book is to ask him, but we have been out of touch by some reasons for years.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure about "blue colored book about projective geometry $\dots$ on sheep or goat covers." But you can search in Amazon. Usually the search results comes with pictures of books. See if you can find something there.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone.

It was "Geometry of Conics" by A. V. Akopyan (Author), A. A. Zaslavsky (Author).